# Variadic template arguments passed to template function

Tags: c++, templates

I have class which accepts one `int` template parameter, and one `int` parameter pack (`neurons`). One of the constructor's goals is to take each of the parameters in the pack and add an instance of a class to a vector. The class, however, takes its arguments as template parameters.

I have the following code:

```
template<int iCount, int... neurons>
class network {
private:
    std::vector<pl> layers;
public:
    network() : layers() {
        input_layer<iCount> inp;
        layers.push_back(inp);
        addLayer<iCount, neurons...>();
    }
    template<int prev, int nc, int... further>
    void addLayer() {
        layer<nc, prev> l;
        layers.push_back(l);
        addLayer<nc, further...>(); // error is here
    }
};
```

The recursive call, which is labeled with 'error is here', produces a compiler error: "Error    4   error C2783: 'void network<1,3,2,1>::addLayer(void)' : could not deduce template argument for 'nc'"

`pl` is the parent class of both `input_layer` and `layer`.

At the moment, I using `network` like so:

```
network<1, 3,2,1> n;
```

After invoking the constructor, I would expect that n.layers would contain four elements. The first being an `input_layer`, to which `iCount` was passed, and the remained being `layer`s with the corresponding entry in `neurons` as its `nc`, and the previous layer's `nc` as its `prev`.

Comment: You're missing a base case.

Comment: Where is your testcase? ([Here it is](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a3ac1057e7327d1))

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049877/c11-recursive-variadic-templates and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035889/compilation-error-on-recursive-variadic-template-function.

Comment: sizeof...(neurons) might be useful, here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all, you have [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/2069064), so you want:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<pl>> layers;
```

Next, we can do this in one function without any recursion:

```
network() : layers() {
    layers.push_back(std::make_unique<input_layer<iCount>>());
    addLayers<iCount, neurons...>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(neurons)>());
}

template <int... Pack, size_t... Is>
void addLayers(std::index_sequence<Is...> )  {
    static constexpr int array[] = {Pack...};

    int unused[] = {0,
        (layers.push_back(std::make_unique<layer<array[Is+1],array[Is]>>()), 0)...
    };
    (void)unused;
}
```

This solution inspired by T.C.'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30776807/2069064).

Comment: I'm having trouble finding an include file for `make_index_sequence` in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Jack It's in [`<utility>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence). If VC doesn't have it, then there are various implementations posted around here. For example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17424477/2069064)

Comment: Visual Studio does not support `constexpr` as you used it. What's an alternative?

Comment: @Jack A quick hack is `template<size_t Index, int...Is> using at_t = std::tuple_element_t<Index, std::tuple<std::integral_constant<int, Is>...>>;`, then use `at_t<Is+1, Pack...>::value` instead of `array[Is+1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You might use tag dispatching to populate the vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<int... neurons>

class network {
public:
    std::vector<int> layers;

private:
    template <int N, int... Ns>
    struct tag {};

    template <int N, int... Ns>
    void addLayer(tag<N, Ns...>) {
        layers.push_back(N);
        addLayer(tag<Ns...>());
    }

    template <int N>
    void addLayer(tag<N>) {
        layers.push_back(N);
    }

public:
    network() {
        layers.reserve(sizeof ... (neurons));
        addLayer(tag<neurons...>());
    }
};

int main()
{
  network<1,2,3,4,5> n;
  for(int i : n.layers)
      std::cout << i;
  std::cout << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Note: Here the the count is determined by the number of integers passed to the template.